# CBCentralManager state is always off

Tags: swift, osx-mavericks, core-bluetooth

When I run my code, and turn on/off the bluetooth on my MacbookPro, the state is always `4`, which corresponds to the `PoweredOff` state.

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var centralManager = CBCentralManager()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {

        switch central.state {

            case .PoweredOn:
                println(".PoweredOn")

            case .PoweredOff:
                println(".PoweredOff")

            case .Resetting:
                println(".Resetting")

            case .Unauthorized:
                println(".Unauthorized")

            case .Unknown:
                println(".Unknown")

            case .Unsupported:
                println(".Unsupported")
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the Bluetooth is in-fact on, because I have been able to pair it with my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It turns out that `CoreBluetooth` is only for Bluetooth 4.0:

> The Core Bluetooth framework is an abstraction of the Bluetooth 4.0 specification [(source)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor)

To find out what bluetooth specification your mac has:

` > About This Mac > More Info... > System Report... > Hardware > Bluetooth`

Look for the `LMP Version`

```
0x4 = Bluetooth Core Specification 2.1 + EDR
0x6 = Bluetooth Core Specification 4.0
```

---

I have LMP version 4, so `CoreBluetooth` won't work for me I guess.

Its interesting that the switch statement wasn't giving me the `.Unsupported` case though.

---

Edit:
After testing the exact same code on a newer mac with bluetooth 4, the state became `.PoweredOn`.

Comment: If you didn't get the unsupported state on your machine, then that is most probably a bug.